# Is it possible to log who started or stopped a windows service?

Tags: c#, windows-services

I have some windows services written in C#.  When somebody stops or starts the service, I would like to be able to determine who it was and log that information.

I tried logging `Environment.UserName` but that evaluates to SYSTEM even on my local machine.

Also, for the time being these services are running on Windows 2000 server.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Within the Event Viewer (Control Panel | Administrative Tools | Event Viewer) on the System tab the Service Control Manager logs who started and stop each event.  I've just tested this myself and viewed the results.  This leads me to two things:

1. You may be able to query or hook those events from the Service Control Manager as they happen, or
2. You can definitely just query the Event Viewer's "System" log to look for those events for your Service.

Hope that leads you to your solution.

Comment: Yes! That's what I was looking for.  I just need a way to find out who stopped the service and there it is - in the system event log. Thanks!

Comment: `Within the Event Viewer (Control Panel | Administrative Tools | Event Viewer) on the System tab the Service Control Manager logs who started and stop each event.`   I see nothing of the sort. All I see is a message like `The Workstation service entered the running state.` but nothing about what process/service caused it to start, even in the details. The closest thing to a cause is the *Source* field which other than Windows Update, is pretty much always the Service Controller (well duh) which says nothing about who/what asked the SC to run the service.

Comment: It's true, I just confirmed my answer from over four years ago is no longer working in the same way.  It seems the Service Control Manager does not log its own Start and Stop events anymore, or at least not in the same place.  (I just retested this in Windows 8. I may have been on Windows XP when I wrote that other answer, but I'm not sure.)

Answer (score 9):

- You can filter the System EventLog by Service Control Manager
  [image]

Event ID 7040 - covers Service start type change (eg disabled, manual, automatic)

Event ID 7036 - covers Service start/stop

[image]

For others that have PowerShell, you can use this:

```
get-eventlog -source "Service Control manager" -LogName System | select message, timegenerated, username | Out-GridView
```

[image]

Comment: not working for me, win 10 x64 20h2. Not sure if a policy or a different setting. It's weird that it doesn't log those events as they're crucial part of any troubleshooting :(

Answer (score 2):

You can enable auditing according to [this article](https://www.itprotoday.com/windows-78/access-denied-auditing-users-who-might-be-starting-and-stopping-services).

Additionally, it may be a good idea to alert email to yourself in `OnStop()` method.

Comment: Maybe I'm doing something wrong, but auditing does not log who started/stopped the service for me on Windows 10. It just says it was services.exe.

Answer (score 0):

There probably isn't a way. Any of the normal .NET ways that you get at the environment's user are going to return the user whose credentials the service runs with (which will typically be SYSTEM, LOCAL SERVICE, NETWORK SERVICE, etc).

How I'd probably do it is poll the system to see if a user is logged in, and assume that user did it. Of course, this discounts services that are shut down by the system for some reason (presumably your service would not be), and can only help you narrow it down if more than one user is logged in at one time (but then, you could always log both of them).

Comment: Considering it that it can be done remotely, or not by the user at all, this seems to carry a risk of blaming the innocent.

Answer (score 0):

1. Just open Event Viewer (Start menu -> Search "Event" Event Viewer will come, open it)
2. Expand 'Windows Log' on Event viewer left menu.
3. Click on Application. (It will show your application error with description in 'general' tab.
4. Again try to start your service and from event viewer see what is exact cause for stopping briefly in 'general' tab.

Comment: Completely fails to answer the question.

Comment: I think the question is about how to determine who *intentionally* stops a service. This answer explains how to figure out why a service executable crashes, another common reason that services stop.