# Powershell Commands /Windows Process

Tags: windows, powershell

Do we have any command in powershell which will provide details on the source of who initiated the stop command?

I have a process which seems to be receiving a stop signal. However, I'm not sure on which source/process is invoking this signal.

I was unable to find any powershell commands as well. Any thoughts

Comment: please take a look at this S-O Question &the Answer >>> c# - Is it possible to log who started or stopped a windows service? - Stack Overflow — https://stackoverflow.com/questions/496632/is-it-possible-to-log-who-started-or-stopped-a-windows-service

Comment: I missed checking the user details in there. Thank you very much

Comment: you are most welcome! glad to have helped a bit ... [*grin*]